# Console app slower than asp.net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a crawlerbot which downloads various pages in parallel using parallel.for and parallel.foreach. The MaxDegreeOfParallelism is set to around 20 since increasing it does not seem to improve the performance further and I do not want to overload any web servers.

When I start the crawling from an ASP.NET website (of all places), it is running with acceptable performance and it all takes a few hours. Due to the design issues with this setup, I am changing this so I can start it from the console instead.

All the code I need is in a dll that can be accessed by both the website and the console app.

There is no output to the console except for a startup message.

The problem is that when I run this from the console (or from the debugger), it takes about 10 times longer(!) than when I run it from the ASP.NET website. I would have found it easier to understand if the ASP.NET version would be slower than the console.

Why is this so or how can I debug this or find out why it is so or fix the problem?

**Edit:** 
This also happens in when trying both variants through the visual studio debugger.
The output to the 'Output' window from 'Debug' is similar to:

The thread '' (0x1d34) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0xf20) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x3414) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x35c8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0xdc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x1c98) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x3308) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x2b00) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x2f7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x345c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x2a18) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x138) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x3650) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '' (0x376c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

except that in the ASP.NET case this text is written about 10 times faster.

Perhaps it could also be worth mentioning that the dll invokes 7zip via COM for each downloaded page to compress it.

Comment: Are you running the code on the same hardware in both cases?

Comment: Yes, all of it is running on my development machine.

Comment: Does it download lots of pages from the same server? What are the values of [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx) and [`ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepoints.aspx) in both environments? Have you tried to figure out where exactly is the slowdown?

Comment: There is way too little information here to do more than guess at the cause. @svick's suggestion is a good one. You need to do some profiling to determine where the slowdown is.

Comment: @svick It tries to download a lot of pages from the same host name at the same time, yes. DefaultConnectionLimit=2 for the console application and DefaultConnectionLimit=2147483647 for the ASP.NET application. (Are there other major differences between settings for an ASP.NET and a console application?) Changing the DefaultConnectionLimit to 80 at the start of the console application made the console application almost as fast as the ASP.NET application. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're downloading lots of pages from the same server, you are going to run into the limit set by [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx). The default value is usually 2 ([as suggested by the HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4)), but it seems it's 10 for ASP.NET applications. If you're seeing a different number, it's likely that something changed the default value.

When you reach this limit, the framework won't make any more connections to that particular server (or “endpoint”), so most of your threads will block doing nothing.

You can fix this by changing the value of the `DefaultConnectionLimit`, but a better solution might be to change the order of your requests, so that you're not doing many simultaneous requests to the same server.